# GCP ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am getting ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED error for all three asia-south1 region from last 24 hours. It is new gcp account created 4-5 days, and yesterday created project and am trying to launch  new instance in asia-south1, but every time I am getting this error for all three zones.

I tried with my another organisation which I am using from last 1 years and able to launch instance in asia-south1. Not sure why this is happening for only new project.

The zone 'projects/<PROJECT_ID>/zones/asia-south1-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.

Answer (score 2):

If you see 'ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED' error meaning you are encountered with the temporary resource stock-out issue at that particular zone. This error is due to Compute Engine resource obtainability, and is not due to your Compute Engine quota.

When you start an instance (or change it) it requests resources like vCPU and memory and if there's not enough resources available in the zone you'll get an error message:

```
Error: The zone 'projects/thetourking/zones/asia-south1-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.
```

You can read more detailed information about that errors in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#resource_availability).

There are various recommended workarounds:

- Move your instances to [another zone](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-compute-engine-region-selection) following this [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#moving-an-instance-manually).
- Wait for a while and try to start your VM instance again because those issues are to be expected transiently.
- [Reserve zonal resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) for your instances to avoid the same issue in the future. Keep in mind that reserving zonal resources requires an extra payment.